One time pad documentary - advance notice
For the masses of one time pad fans in the UK, there's a documentary about the Venona Project tonight.  See this wiki article for some background, and would be useful for all those nay sayers that insist one time pads are useless  ;-)
This is probably only the second documentary type on encryption I've seen.  They're usually about Bletchley's efforts regarding Enigma.  It's on Yesterday channel, 5 Feb 2016, 2200hrs (GMT), called "Secrets, Lies and Atomic Spies"

Let me know if it ever makes it online anywhere.
